# Registering a transaction using only tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to register a transaction in a website using nothing but the Tag Manager? So without any modification of the website itself? I already have a trigger that fires at the right moment that registers an event.

I don't care about the value of the transaction id, or the total value of the transaction; except they're required so I need to find a way of generating a unique transaction id.

I am aware how pointless this makes a transaction, but I have a customer who insists because ... I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions require a unique transaction id. How do you plan on handling that? You could use the Javascript date function for this, and run a Javascript function as a tag that throws the transaction code.

Simo Ahava has written a [fairly detailed piece on this](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/javascript-101-gtm-part-1/). There is also the Google Support Literature on [Ecommerce tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce).